# Molecule mass calculator program in C

Tags: c, chemistry

I need to do a proyect that calculates me the molar mass of any molecule entered by the user. 
For example if the user types CO2, my program needs to identify C (that is associated with a matrix with its mass), then identify O (associated with its mass) and multiply it by two, and add them up.

I was thinking of using strings of character for the each element.

Im very new in programing and I have learned just the basics pretty much.

how would you guys recommend me to do it? Im pretty lost

Thank you very much

Comment: 1. A table of proper atom names along with their mass - a `struct`. 2. Scan for Uppercase, followed optionally by multiple lowercases. 3. Scan digits. 4. Multiply and add. 5. Rinse and repeat until end of string. 6. Profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the big challenge here is parsing the text, so you can pass full elements to a function to do your counting. You'll need a string to take the input, but I would strongly caution you away from the std string for this.

Instead, try an array of char.

Some things to consider:

- How big does the array need to be?
- What kind of characters will I accept? (spaces?)
- How do I know when the user is done with input? (something something null-terminated...)
- How will I move through the array?
- What defines an element? (If it's capital letters, take a look at ASCII values for comparing them)
- What do I do with an element when I find it?

You asked for a starting place, so I'm reluctant to give out any specific code. Take a look at Jongware's comment for a good outline of what your program needs to do. Tackle it a piece at a time (answer the questions in this post and you'll be fine with input) and check it off your outline when you're done. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

While you have one answer, I would suggest taking a hard look at the first comment posted following your question. Regardless how you slice it, you will have to parse the user input in the form of a string. While it may seem daunting to parse something like `"Li3Co4CO2"` to get the atomic weight for each element, multiply it by the correct multiplier and keep a running sum, it can be done with 2 pointers and a nested while loop.

Take for example your user input in `argv[1]` and assign it to pointer `p`:

```
char *p = argv[1];
```

All you need now is a `while` loop to check each character in the string:

```
while (*p) {
```

Within the loop, all you will need to do is to identify each element *a Capital letter followed by any lower case* and a *terminating digit* (if any) before the next Cap or the null-terminating character (end of string). So assign an *end-pointer* say `ep` and work down the string with a nested `while` loop. (we'll add a multiplier to hold the digit, and a symbol length for use later) We skip the first character in `p`, (`char *ep = p + 1;`), so we will initialize the symbol length to `1` as well (the multiplier always starts at 1):

```
    char *ep = p + 1;       /* end pointer  */
    char m = 1;             /* multiplier   */
    size_t symlen = 1;      /* symbol len   */
    ...
    /* for each char in p until next CAP */
    while (*ep && (*ep < 'A' || 'Z' < *ep)) {

        /* if digit */
        if ('0' <= *ep && *ep <= '9') 
            m = *ep - '0';  /* set multiplier */
        else
            symlen++;       /* increment len  */
        ep++;
    }
```

You now have all the information you need to copy/search for the symbol and then add the weight to a running sum. To finish isolating the symbol, you can simply use your `symlen` along with `strncpy` to copy the symbol to a temporary array/string:

```
    char srchsym[8] = {0};  /* search sym   */
    strncpy (srchsym, p, symlen);
    srchsym[symlen] = 0; /* null-terminate */
```

(the manual null-termination is technically not needed since you initialized `srchsym[8] = {0};`, but it is a good habit)

Now all that is left is to search for `srchsym` within your periodic table (array of structs) and return a pointer to the element of the array that corresponds to element that matches your search symbol (the atomic symbol). Once you have a pointer to the data in your periodic table, keeping the running sum in `wt` is as simple as:

```
        wt += (float)m * ptp->atwt;
```

(where `ptp` - pointer to periodic table and the element of the stucture `atwt` is the atomic weight.) With the calculation for the first element done, simply advance your pointer `p` to the next Cap in the string, and repeat:

```
    p = ep;
}
```

When done, you can print your results:

```
printf ("\n %s (atomic weight) : %.3f\n\n", argv[1], wt);
```

If you like, you can also have the loop print out each element it is adding to the sum as it is returned by your search with `srchsym`. An example for the hypothetical `"Li3Co4CO2"` would be:

```
$ ./bin/ptable Li3Co4CO2

 element    : Lithium
 symbol     : Li
 atomic num : 3
 atomic wt. : 6.941

 element    : Cobalt
 symbol     : Co
 atomic num : 27
 atomic wt. : 58.933

 element    : Carbon
 symbol     : C
 atomic num : 6
 atomic wt. : 12.011

 element    : Oxygen
 symbol     : O
 atomic num : 8
 atomic wt. : 15.999

 Li3Co4CO2 (atomic weight) : 300.565
```

Good luck, let me know if you need additional help fitting the pieces together.